# choose the right client certificate - https - ssl related

Tags: apache, ssl

I have this situation

- Apache Web Server configured for https connections and some vhosts. All of them is well running, no problems at all. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- One of this web sites, let's call alfa.com, sends via Soap some messages to a remote server (let's call beta.com)
- alfa.com expose a crt with let'sencrypt. Every users and check is ok, no problems with the certificate.
- This same server, beta.com, sends to alfa.com responses and messages BUT beta.com require a client certificate (exposed by alfa.com) which MUST be one they gave to me
- The cert required by beta.com could not be used as main cert for alfa.com cause it has an untrusted CA and I cannot have my website expose a "this site is insecure"...

How can I use the Let'sEncrypt cert to clients but StrangeCert to beta.com?
Any suggestion is helpful, except for asking beta.com to give another cert, it is impossible.

Apache proxy? Iptables? What else?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
Using iptables and NAT chain, I'm able to redirect the beta.com SSL request in another virtualhost section of Apache, letting untouched the "other world" side.

- Each client on the web reaches alfa.com:443 and do the normal, perfect, handshake with the Let'sEncrypt certs.
  Vhost config

> <VirtualHost *:443>
> ServerName alfa.com
> ServerAlias [www.alfa.com](http://www.alfa.com)
> ....
> SSLCertificateFile /var/www/clients/client1/ssl/sitecert-le.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/clients/client1/ssl/sitecert-le.key
> ....
> </VirtualHost>

- Only the source net corresponding to beta.com (say 1.2.3.0/24) pass trought NAT chain in iptables and go to alfa.com:8080

> <VirtualHost *:8080>
> ServerName alfa.com
> ServerAlias [www.alfa.com](http://www.alfa.com)
> ....
> SSLCertificateFile /var/www/clients/client1/ssl/beta.com.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/clients/client1/ssl/beta.com.key
> ....
> </VirtualHost>

- This is the relevant iptables commands

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 1.2.3.0/20 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:8080
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.10 --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.10

- Of course, to allow only beta.com net to see alfa.com:8080 we can deny access to each other

> iptables -A INPUT -s ! 1.2.3.0/20 -p tcp --destination-port 8080 -j DROP